# Suppress, log and return values in a function with warnings in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

There is a function that has warnings but it doesn't affect the final output. I want to catch the warning to a log, suppress the warning message on console and return the value.

```r
fn1 <- function() {
    warning("this is a warning!")
    return(1)
}
```

I have tried `withCallingHandlers` but the warning message still print out and `tryCatch` blocks the return value. For example, I use `message` to pretend a save to a log.

```r
withCallingHandlers(expr = fn1(),
                    warning = function(w) {
                        message(paste0("saved to a file: ", w$message))
                        # write(w$message, "xxlocation")
                    }
)
```

output

```r
saved to a file: this is a warning!
[1] 1
Warning message:
In fn1() : this is a warning!
```

I can use restart to suppress the warning but my return value is suppressed too. It's very similar to `tryCatch`:

```r
withCallingHandlers(
    withRestarts(fn1(),
                 mufflewarn=function(msg) {
                     message(msg)
                 }),
    warning = function(w) {
        invokeRestart("mufflewarn", w$message)
    }
)
```

```r
this is a warning!
```

Is there any way I can have the output of:

```r
saved to a file: this is a warning!
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the solution is very simple, just use `suppressWarnings` outside will do the trick:

```r
suppressWarnings(withCallingHandlers(expr = fn1(),
                    warning = function(w) {
                        message(paste0("saved to a file: ", w$message))
                        # write(w$message, "xxlocation")
                    },
                    finally = function(x) suppressWarnings(x)
))
```

```r
saved to a file: this is a warning!
[1] 1
```

Comment: You don't need `finally` part `suppressWarnings(withCallingHandlers(expr = fn1(),
                                     warning = function(w) {
                                       message(paste0("saved to a file: ", w$message))
                                     }))` seems to work the same.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forget to delete it. Some redundant code when I try different options.